# Oauth fails to post

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-oauth

I'm trying to post a tweet with oauth but fails with error code 32:"Could not authenticate you", but the access tokens are correct. Below is the object that invokes the post method.

```
function consumer() {
return new oauth.OAuth(
    "https://twitter.com/oauth/request_token", "https://twitter.com/oauth/access_token", 
    _twitterConsumerKey, _twitterConsumerSecret, "1.0A", "http://127.0.0.1:8080/sessions/callback", "HMAC-SHA1");
}
consumer().post("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json", oauthAccessToken, oauthAccessTokenSecret, status, '', function (error, data, response) {
```

(oauth in line 2 comes from [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/oauth))

I know that the credentials are correct, because this line works:

```
consumer().get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json", oauthAccessToken, oauthAccessTokenSecret, function (error, data, response)
```

Comment: Are you sure you can post to this timeline? Check your granted privileges?

Comment: I have the permissions: "read, write and direct messages"